# Error upload smart contract

Tags: parachain, smart-contract

1. The pallet-contract version is 0.9.29
2. Error uploading new contract using Polkadot.JS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with `polkadotjs-ui`, try deploying your contract with https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/, as mentioned in ink documentation https://use.ink/getting-started/deploy-your-contract/#using-the-contracts-ui